# Viewing a bitmap in a fixed space in mfc

Tags: bitmap, mfc, stretchblt

I am trying to design an application that loads bitmap images. I have bitmaps of varying sizes but I want them to be displayed on a constant space ( like a rectangle of size 500x500). I've tried `StretchBlt()` in the following way but the results are disappointing and the images are still of varying sizes. The code is mentioned below. Thanks in advance.

```
DcForClientClientDc.StretchBlt(0, 0 , 500, 500, &bmDC, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, SRCCOPY);
```

Comment: You'll find explanations of the arguments in the documentation for [`StretchBlt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt).

Comment: Also keep in mind the proportions on the image you want to fit. Will they be the same? Otherwise you also need to consider ratios in your scaling so that it fits nicely in the constrained space.

Comment: Why in the name of C++ somebody would downgrade this question, instead explaining to the original poster what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass to `StretchBlt` the actual size of the image you want to scale, but you are using 1000 x 1000.

Comment: thanks for the help . It works now andrew and vlad <3